# How to make sure a user completes their profile in aspnet core 2.0?

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, middleware

I'm new to aspnet core 2.0 and what I would like to accomplish is to redirect a user who has not completed their profile to a page that they can do so. I'm using the default template with user authentication for Identity server.

I have tried using middleware but the page that i redirect to comes out blank. Is this the best approach or can someone help make it work. here is my middleware.

```
public class FarmProfileMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public FarmProfileMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;

    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (!user.EmailConfirmed && !context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("profile"))
            {
                var url = context.Request.PathBase + "/Users/Profile";
                context.Response.Redirect(url);    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just looking at the current logic in your code I notice that if the user is not null and has its profile completed will short circuit the call. You need to add in that logic. This may be an X-Y problem

Comment: Hi @Nkosi, thanks for the quick reply. I have removed the else condition and just called `await next(context);` after the if statement, I'm still getting a blank page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at the current logic in your code I notice that if the user is not null and has its profile completed will short circuit the call. You need to add in that logic.

Try the following

```
var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);
if (user != null && !user.EmailConfirmed && !context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("profile")) { 
    var url = context.Request.PathBase + "/Users/Profile";
    context.Response.Redirect(url);            
} else {
    await next(context);
}
```